ASP.Net Core MVC : compilation errors. How to solve them?
After developing a few ASP.NET Core MVC sites with sorting and searching, that work quite OK, when coming to pagination I met some errors that I did not understand, so I thought working on the demo application would be a good idea.
Well, I get the same errors there: strange, is not it?
I imagine that if there were errors in the demo application that would be well known and quickly corrected, the other hypothesis is an error on my machine.
I hope somebody is able to situate the error, to avoid me the pain of completely reinstalling my machine, which for sure would take ... some time, at least.
First of all, the reference page is there: Tutorial: Add sorting, filtering, and paging - ASP.NET MVC with EF Core
On that page, search "Get the code", and click on "Download or view the completed application".
I was surprised to see a title that begins with "Aspnet-Docs", but somebody by Microsoft confirmed me the link was correct.
I arrive there:
https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/main/aspnetcore/data/ef-mvc/intro/samples/cu-final
then I click on "Code" in the navigation bar on top of the page, then on the "Code" button.
I obtain a "Clone" interface, that gives me this URL to clone:
https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs.git
So, in Visual Studio 2022 I start a new session, click on "Clone a repository", and paste that URL.
When launching the execution I see nothing persuasive. No application window appears.
After updating Visual Studio 2022 to Version 4.8.09032, I launch execution again, and it raises four errors.
Perhaps it is best to first give the original (localised) version for each from the errors window, before translating it to English.

Erreur (active) CS0234
Le nom de type ou d'espace de noms 'Entity' n'existe pas dans l'espace de noms 'System.Data' (vous manque-t-il une référence d'assembly ?)    MVCStudents01   C:\Projects Visual Studio\Web\MVCStudents01\MVCStudents01\DAL\SchoolInitializer.cs  10      " `
Error CS0234: the type name or namespace 'Entity' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data'. (Are you missing an assembly reference ?)


Erreur (active) CS1503
Argument 1 : conversion impossible de 'string' en 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions'    MVCStudents01   C:\Projects Visual Studio\Web\MVCStudents01\MVCStudents01\DAL\SchoolContextt.cs 11      "`
Error CS1503 Argument 1 : impossible conversion from 'string' to 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCode.DbContextOptions'


Erreur (active) CS0246
Le nom de type ou d'espace de noms 'DbModelBuilder' est introuvable (vous manque-t-il une directive using ou une référence d'assembly ?)  MVCStudents01   C:\Projects Visual Studio\Web\MVCStudents01\MVCStudents01\DAL\SchoolContextt.cs 20      "`
Error CS0246: the type name of namespace 'DbModelBuilder' cannot be found (Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference ?)


Erreur (active) CS0246
Le nom de type ou d'espace de noms 'PluralizingTableNameConvention' est introuvable (vous manque-t-il une directive using ou une référence d'assembly ?)  MVCStudents01   C:\Projects Visual Studio\Web\MVCStudents01\MVCStudents01\DAL\SchoolContextt.cs 22      "`
Error CS0246: the type name or namespace 'PluralizingTableNameConvention' cannot be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

So, maybe after taking some distance it will be obvious that I forgot to install something. It is possible that somebody can be quicker than I on this.
As I said, when seeing errors in my code, I tried cloning the demo application, and saw, at least partially, the same errors.

The code at https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs.git does not have (As far as I can see) code that is in a folder MVCStudents01.

Hum ... my first reaction was to refer to Microsoft, to verify there was no error. They sent me to Stackoverflow, as appears in the linked conversion.
A demo application is usually supposed to be complete, is not it?

Something else hearts me ... HomeController is the only controller, and with that we are supposed to show a paginated list of students.

@luuk
I tried and confirm what you said. I see no MVCStudent01 directory, except the main folder, the one of the project. This name has been given to the default namespace. Do you still see something missing at that level?

I am not much used to quotations in posts, I see that Luuk's name does not appear as a link maybe because I did not write it with the good case? Perhaps better like this ? @Luuk

I think you should start here doing you MVC research Create web app, and then follow that tutorial.   The download link is just to download the code, and seems to not provide a Solution file (a .sln file)

The reason for not being able to use @luuk to me is because there are multiple users with my name   (see: https://stackoverflow.com/users, and search for Luuk ). when searching for user3500176 you will only find 1 hit

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

For the moment being, Luuk seems no more available (or he did not see updates to the chat conversation). For the moment it seems my first problem is with the cloning process. There are several controllers in the demo application, but they did not land on my machine.

You can try to download the sample demo directly from this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/introduction-to-aspnet-core?view=aspnetcore-8.0#how-to-download-a-sample, unzip it, and use the URL in the target sample link https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/main/aspnetcore/data/ef-mvc/intro/samples/cu-final to help you navigate to the folder of the sample you need.

I tried that, yes (maybe there are errors in the media to clone, that there are not in the zip). But it was far from obvious, where to find an MVC page with pagination.

I've provided the relevant paths that you can use as a reference.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/sort-filter-page?view=aspnetcore-8.0#add-paging-to-students-index From this link, we can see that we first need to use the PaginatedList.cs CreateAsync method to extract the page size and page number.
For the relevant path, you can refer to：
aspnetcore/data/ef-mvc/intro/samples/cu-final/PaginatedList.cs
Secondly, need to configure the Index method in StudentsController.cs
For the relevant path, you can refer to:
aspnetcore/data/ef-mvc/intro/samples/cu-final/Controllers/StudentsController.cs

Configure the relevant views in Views/Students/Index.cshtml. The relevant path is:
aspnetcore/data/ef-mvc/intro/samples/cu-final/Views/Students/Index.cshtml


That definitely seems very helpful.
I have a tendency to develop after starting fro a wrong platform while following a documentation, so I have to read all that carefully and then I tell you how I evolve.

I had configuration problems that prevented me to develop in MVC during a few weeks.
As advised, I reinstalled .NET 8, MVC, Entity Framework.
It first could compile, but produced a white page.
Then, a Visual Studio 2022 update, after spending a lot of my communication credits, eventually led to being able to develop in ASP.Net Core MVC on Entity Framework again.
I am now focusing on the pagination for it, which is the topic of this thread. Most of the threads I saw on this question those last weeks advised to code that oneself.
